# Can I add a local instance of a pointer to a struct with memory allocated with malloc to a global array of structs and free() properly

Tags: arrays, c, struct, memory-leaks

## Problem

Valgrind is informing me of a memory leak, however no matter what I cannot seem to figure out how I haven't freed all my allocated memory, leading to the question in my title. I won't provide my full code so I also won't attach the entire valgrind report, but I will point out where valgrind think the problem is.

## Some code to further explain what is going on

assume all memory allcations are checked for error, assume while loop teminates eventually

```
struct s1{
  int total_s2; // assume some code initialise this to 0
  struct s2 **arr_s2;
} struct1;

struct s2{
  char *important_string
};


void add_s2_to_s1(struct s2 *struct2){
  struct1.arr_s2 = realloc(s1.arr_s2, sizeof(struct s2 *) * s1.total_s2);
  struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));  // !mem lost!
  struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = struct2;
}

// in main
while(some_string){
  struct s2 *struct2 = malloc(sizeof(*struct2));
  struct2->important_string = malloc(sizeof(some_string) + 1);
  s1.total_s2++;
  add_s2_to_s1(struct2);

  // some code to change some_string
}

for(int i = 0; i < total_s2; i++){
  free(s1.arr_s2[i]->important_string);
  free(s1.arr_s2[i]);
}
free(s1.arr_s2);
```

## Bit more on my understanding

Even though `struct2` is technically lost each iteration of the while loop, the pointer to the memory of `struct2` should be stored in the array in `struct1`, and thus should be able to be freed no problem.

Worst part with mem leak issues are my program is doing exactly what I want it to do right now, so it is very tempting to throw my hands in the air and move on. But I know I should fix it otherwise it might come back and bite me in the ass later.

Comment: The code you are showing is not freeing the struct itself.  Just count the `malloc`/`realloc` calls and `free` calls. You will see that you don't have the same number of these.

Comment: `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = struct2;` should be `*(struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1]) = *struct2;`. You want to copy the struct to the allocated memory, not overwrite the pointer.

Comment: What comes immediately after the `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));` line? Yep - you are overwriting that allocated pointer with something else. So how can you ever free the memory whose address you no longer have.

Comment: YES! @mch this is too good, from all I have read, I always thought an assignment like what I did is the same as copying the struct. Much thanks.

Comment: @EugeneSh. initially my understanding is I dont have to `free(struct2);` because I thought I have stored its memory location into the array in struct1, and therefore can free it with the line `free(s1.arr_s2[i])`. But with @mch's comment, I realise now I can `free(struct2);` in the while loop as I have copied the struct over into `s1.arr_s2[i]`.

Comment: @mch But then where is `struct s2 *struct2 = malloc(sizeof(*struct2));` in `main` is freed?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that is missing from my code, combining mch and Eugene Sh.'s answer, I needed to copy struct2 to my array according to what mch said, and free `struct2` in the while loop.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(some_string) + 1)` should most likely be `malloc(strlen(some_string) + 1)`.

Comment: You could do that, but a much simpler solution would be to just remove the line marked "mem lost" and leave everything else in place. Since this line literally does absolutely nothing except leaking memory, removing it should not affect the correctness of the program.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, typo in the question

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I was confused by the code. In this case the line is correct and the one above should be removed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I thought I need to allocate memory for every index to the array? E.g. if I want `**some_array` to hold 4 things each of 4 bytes, I need to `malloc(4*4)` to `some_array` and run a for loop, allocating 4 bytes to `some_array[0]` to `some_array[3]`.

Comment: I stopped understanding you. You have an array of pointers. Each element of the array points to an individually allocated `struct` If. It does so now, then it will continue to do so after you remove that line, *because that line has no effect apart from losing memory*. Where does this memory come from in your current version of the program? Look for the other call to `malloc`. 
 It's that place. It will not change when you remove that line.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I read from somewhere (I can't find it anymore) I need to specifically allocate memory to hold x amount of pointers, hence the line `struct1.arr_s2 = realloc(s1.arr_s2, sizeof(struct s2 *) * s1.total_s2);`, on top of this, for each instance of the pointer being stored in this array, I need to allocate memory to store the pointers, hence the line `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));  // !mem lost!` I would really appreciate it if you wrote an answer showing your approach? I think that will help me understand better.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. because I can see that my understanding is very convoluted and most likely incorrect, so seeing what you mean and how you can improve what I have will be very valuable.

Comment: The array itself is allocated correctly. Nothing is lost there. What happens on top of this **is** problematic. The line marked "// !mem lost!" loses memory, but otherwise **has no effect**. You need to understand this fact, otherwise there is little hope to advance further. Here is a simple illustration. `int x; x = 2 + 3; x = 42;` Do you think the line `x = 2 + 3;` has any effect? Now compare this to `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));  struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = struct2;` What difference do you see between this example and my simplified example?

Comment: If you think you need the line marked "// !mem lost!", do a simple experiment. **Remove it and see what happens**. If not convinced, replace it with `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = NULL;`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes you are absolutely right. I tried doing what you said and it works as well, thinking about it a bit more I also understand why it works now. My misunderstanding was I intended for `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));  // !mem lost!` to "partition" the big block of memory allocated by `struct1.arr_s2 = realloc(s1.arr_s2, sizeof(struct s2 *) * s1.total_s2);` but that way of thinking is completely **incorrect**. Thanks again for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line allocates some bytes and stores a pointer to those bytes in the variable `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1]`:

```
struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct s2));  // !mem lost!
```

This line stores a pointer to some other bytes in the variable `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1]`:

```
struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1] = struct2;
```

As you know, a variable only has one value at a time. The variable `struct1.arr_s2[total_s2 - 1]` now contains the same value as the variable `struct2` - it doesn't somehow remember the other value you gave it (the address of some newly allocated bytes).